# Custom object mapper for Websockets in Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, websocket, spring-4

I'm using Spring 4 and was following the [Rossen Stoyanchev's blog post](http://assets.spring.io/wp/WebSocketBlogPost.html) about using websockets in Spring. I was able to get everything working but I'm not sure what the best way to use a custom object mapper when sending `application/json`.

I'm injecting a `SimpMessageSendingOperations` and calling `convertAndSend`. I'm not positive but I'm pretty sure I'm getting a `SimpMessagingTemplate` (it implements `SimpMessageSendingOperations`) which contains a `setMessageConverter`. This method takes a `MessageConverter` and there is a `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` class but of course it uses it's own internal `ObjectMapper` which cannot be redefined.

So what it looks like I have to do is create a custom `MessageConverter` and define my custom `ObjectMapper` within it so I can pass it to an instance of `SimpMessagingTemplate` that I can then inject into my classes.

This seems like it would work, but also more involved than I expected. Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it is possible, but will be made easier in Spring 4.0.1

See - https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-11184

Quote from the bug report above.

> In the mean time, with @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker setup you can:
>
> 1. remove the annotation
> 2. extend WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport instead of implementing WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer
> 3. override brokerMessageConverter() method and remember to keep @Bean in the overriding method

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays you can do it like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public boolean configureMessageConverters(List<MessageConverter> messageConverters) {
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        // Avoid creating many ObjectMappers which have the same configuration.
        converter.setObjectMapper(getMyCustomObjectMapper());
        messageConverters.add(converter);

        // Don't add default converters.
        return false;
    }

    ...
}
```

Unfortunately `ObjectMapper` cannot be given directly to `MappingJackson2MessageConverter`'s constructor, meaning it will first create a useless ObjectMapper.